# Curly braces inside curly braces in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, jsx

I have presentational component in React. And with `products.some` i am trying to check if any item inside `products` is checked. And if some item is checked, render parent block for `RequestedProduct` component. I know that the problem is a second pair of curly braces as React think it's a prop. Is there another way to do this?

```
const Requested = ({ products, getCurrentTime }) => (
  <div className="pepper-pin-body-tab requested-tab">
    <div className="pepper-pin-body-tab-title">
      Запрошенные
    </div>
    <div className="pepper-pin-body-tab-indicator" />
    {products.some(product => product.checked) ? (
      <div className="requested-tab-list-requested">
        <div className="requested-tab-list-requested-time">
          {getCurrentTime()}
        </div>
        {products.filter((product, key) => {
          if (product.checked) {
            return (
              <RequestedProduct
                key={key}
                title={product.title}
              />
            );
          }
        })}
      </div>
    ) : null}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: does is print any error?

Comment: Which line you mean is issue with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is, [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will not return the custom element/value, it will always return the array element for which you return true from filter body.

Solution is, use only map or combination of filter and map.

Using map:

```
{
    products.map((product, key) => product.checked ? 
        <RequestedProduct key={key} title={product.title} /> 
        : null
}
```

Using combination of filter and map:

```
{
    products
    .filter(product => product.checked)
    .map((product, key) => <RequestedProduct key={key} title={product.title}/>)
}
```

Check this snippet, you will get a better idea:

```js
const arr = [
  {a: 1},
  {a: 2},
  {a: 3},
  {a: 4}
];

const afterFilter = arr.filter((el,i) => {
  if(i%2) {
    return `Hello world ${i}`;
  }
});

// it will print the array items, not the Hello World string
console.log('afterFilter', afterFilter);
```

Comment: Thanks for help and explaining

Comment: glad, that helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recomment splitting the code a bit, which makes it intent a lot clearer. You'll end up with the following (for example), which should not be triggering errors.

The main problem is in the unintended side effects of the filter, whereas you most likely want to use a `filter` and a `map`. That makes the intent to another developer much clearer.

```js
const contents = (products, getCurrentTime) => (
    const filtered = products.filter(product => product.checked);
    <div className="requested-tab-list-requested">
        <div className="requested-tab-list-requested-time">
            {getCurrentTime()}
        </div>
        {filtered.map((product, key) => <RequestedProduct key={key} title={product.title}/>)}
    </div>  
);

const Requested = ({products, getCurrentTime}) => {
    const isAnythingChecked = products.some(product => product.checked);

    return <div className="pepper-pin-body-tab requested-tab">
        <div className="pepper-pin-body-tab-title">
            Запрошенные
        </div>
        <div className="pepper-pin-body-tab-indicator"/>
        {isAnythingChecked ? contents(products, getCurrentTime) : null}
    </div>
};
```